# Click play button in Google Apps Script with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, greasemonkey

I am coding a Greasemonkey script to click the play button for a script in Google Apps Script every five 5 minutes to avoid the execution time limit set by Google.

I was able to identify with the script when the time is over but am unable to click the "run" button by using JavaScript. I have been inspecting the button with Google Chrome and tried a few things but I couldn't make it work.

Can anyone please help me?

I guess clicking any button in the toolbar of Google Sheets would be exactly the same..

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of greasemonkey use a time-driven trigger. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers

Comment: or an html that catches the timeout error and calls again the script.

Comment: I am downvoting this question because it shows zero research effort. You just made a screenshot of console. Where is your code that doesn't work as you expect? Read also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this in a completely wrong way. You should be including the possibility to restart the execution with a trigger internally in your script. I will show you how I did it. Keep in mind that my script is quite large and it performs a loop and I had to make it remember where in the loop it stopped, so it could continue with the same data.

```
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Purpose: Check if there is enough time left for another data output run
// Input:   Start time of script execution
// Output:  Boolean value if time is up
function isTimeUp(start, need) {  
  var cutoff = 500000 // in miliseconds (5 minutes)
  var now = new Date();
  return cutoff - (now.getTime() - start.getTime()) < need; 
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here the `start` is simply a `new Date()` that you create when you start the script. The `need` is simply an average time it takes for my script to perform 1 loop. If there is not enough time for a loop, we will cut off the script with another function.

```
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Purpose: Store current properties and create a trigger to start the script after 1 min
// Input:   propertyCarrier object (current script execution properties)
// Output:  Created trigger ID
function autoTrigger(passProperties, sysKeys) {  
  var sysProperties = new systemProperties();

  if (typeof sysKeys === 'undefined' || sysKeys === null) {
    sysKeys = new systemKeys();
  }

  var triggerID = ScriptApp.newTrigger('stateRebuild')
                           .timeBased()
                           .after(60000)
                           .create()
                           .getUniqueId();

  Logger.log('~~~ RESTART TRIGGER CREATED ~~~');

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// In order to properly retrieve the time later, it is stored in milliseconds
  passProperties.timeframe.start = passProperties.timeframe.start.getTime();
  passProperties.timeframe.end = passProperties.timeframe.end.getTime();
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Properties are stored in User Properties using JSON
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
                   .setProperty(sysKeys.startup.rebuildCache, JSON.stringify(passProperties));
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Logger.log('~~~ CURRENT PROPERTIES STORED ~~~');
  return triggerID;
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Yours can be more simplistic if you do not need to remember where you stopped (judging by your current implementation you do not care whether you start from the beginning or not).

The trigger you create should either aim at the main function or if you need to pass on the data like I do, you will need to have a separate starter function to get the data back from the user properties and pass it on.